# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento2, database

I do not know where I am wrong.

```
db' => [
    'table_prefix' => 'astro',
    'connection' => [
      'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'astrokapoor_new',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'dayzero',
        'active' => '1'
      ]
    ]
  ],
```

Comment: check database with root username and password is working ?

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions